# many to many mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, entity

I gave uni association having many to many relationship between two entities, from **C** to **CG**

It is referred in **C** entity's hbm.xml as

```
    <set name="cG" table="C_G2C" order-by="C_G_FK"     lazy="true" fetch="select" inverse="false">
        <key foreign-key="C_G_C_FKC">
            <column name="C_FK" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="CGImpl" foreign key="C_C_G_FKC">
            <column name="C_G_FK" sql-type="BIGINT"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

My Table Structure in DB is
@entity
**C**
c_id,
c_name,
c_g_fk

@entity
**CG**
cg_id,
cg_name

when I try to call c.getCG(),

The following error is thrown

ERROR: relation "c_g2c" does not exist

I could'nt trace the problem
could someone help..plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an intermediate entity solved the problem